# How to get matplotlib's stream / quiver to plot in image coordinates

Tags: image, matplotlib

Is there a way to get matplotlib's `quiver` and `streamplot` functions to use the image coordinate convention (origin at the upper-left corner, +y points down), rather than the standard coordinate convention (origin at lower-left corner, +y points up)?

Context:

I'm using both `quiver` and `streamplot` to visualize optical flow fields between two images. You can see an example below.

[image: Optical flow visualization using streamplot]

Unfortunately, `quiver` and `streamplot` both expect the flow field to be defined in conventional coordinates, whereas my flow field is defined in image coordinates.

In the image above, I manually converted the flow to conventional coordinates before passing it to `streamplot`. The streamlines shows up correctly, but the axis labels are still in conventional coordinates. Notice how they disagree with the axis labels of the top two images.

I could manually convert axis labels as well, but is there some simpler way for me to just get `streamplot` and `quiver` to understand that the flow field is defined in the image coordinate convention, and should be displayed as such (origin at upper-left, +y points down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exactly mimic the display of the image axes (including the `0.5` offset and the inversion of the y axis), then you can should retrieve the x and y limits of one of the first two `axes` and then apply them to your `streamplot` axes

```
hax1 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
hax1.imshow(image1)

hax2 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
hax2.imshow(image2)

hax3 = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
hax3.streamplot(x, y, u, v)
hax3.set_xlim(hax1.get_xlim())
hax3.set_ylim(hax1.get_ylim())
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't just reverse the y axis label, but also flips the plot vertically (and shifts the origin to the upper-left). So now I don't have to convert the flow field from image coordinates to conventional coordinates before passing it to quiver/streamplot. Perfect!

Comment: (after your addition of set_xlim, set_ylim): Cool; I had been shifting the flow field's x & y coords by [.5, .5] manually, but I had forgotten that this wasn't reflected in the axes. Now I can pass in the flow coordinates as is, unshifted and unflipped, and have both the streamplot / quiver plot and the axes labels be consistent with imshow.